# Transport equation without charasteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering if the characteristics of a transport equation blow-up, does it mean that the solution blow-up (for a smooth solution) ?

If we consider the example

$$\partial_t f +\frac{y}{|y|} \partial_x f + h(x) \partial_y f=0,$$
with $f(0,.,.)=f_0$ a smooth function (with $f_0 \geq 1$ if $|(x,y)| \leq 1$ and $f_0=0$ if $|(x,y)| \geq 10$) and $h$ a smooth function with $h \geq 1$ for $|x| \leq 5$.

Then, if we consider the characteristic $(X(s),Y(s))$, with $(X(0),Y(0))=(1,-\epsilon)$, then we have (for $s <6$), $X(s)=1-s$ and $Y(s) \geq -\epsilon+s$.
So $\forall$ $T>0$, we can find initial data $(X(0),Y(0))$ such that the characteristic $(X(s),Y(s))$ blow-up before the value $T$. ($Y$ take the value $0$).

So the method of characteristics doesn't give us a smooth local solution. But does that mean that we haven't any smooth local solution ? And why ?

Thanks !

Comment: I wouldn't say that the characteristic curve blows up, it just reaches a point where it cannot be defined (because the coefficients of the equation are discontinuous). How do you interpret the equation for $y=0$?

Comment: Yes, you're right, "blow up" is not the good word. But the method of characteristics doesn't give us a smooth solution, but does it mean that there is no smooth solution ?

Comment: If $h=1$, then we have $f(t,x,y)=f_0(x-\int_0^t\frac{y-t+s}{|y|-t+s}ds, y-t)$. Then  if $y-t >0$, there's no problem : $f_0(x-t,v-t)$, but if $y>0$ and $y-t < 0$, we can try $f_0(x+t-2y,y-t)$. But this function is not $C^1$ in all $(t,x,t)$ such that $\partial_x f_0 (x,0) \neq 0$. So if the equation have only one continous solution, it's probably mean that there's no $C^1$ solution ?

Comment: I can't edit but it was " $f(t,x,v)=f_0(x-\int_0^t \frac{y-t+s}{|y-t+s|},y-t)$". and "such that $\partial_x f_0(x-t,0) \neq 0$.". And a continous solition would be a weak solution.